# What does "pink primates" mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

What does this sentence mean?

> What was over there?
>   Freaky  pink primates!

Why 'pink' ? What is the exact meaning?

It was in Over the Hedge.

Comment: I have a feeling this is purely contextual, referring to humans as "pink primates"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the characters in "Over the Hedge" are animals.

Imagine you were an animal and all the beings you've ever been exposed to are other animals. Then you see human beings for the first time. How would "they" appear to you?

Freaky, pink primates.

Monkeys, which the film's characters are familiar with, are all black because of the hair covering their bodies.

This is the first time "pink" monkeys have ever been sighted – monkeys with no hair.

Comment: No problem. I remember it vaguely :-)

Comment: Actually I saw your profile and I've got you are a teacher, could you please tell me how can I improve my English skills? I really think my English is terrible :(

Comment: There's no shortcut or secret formula, if that's what you're hoping for. It takes a lot of time, regular practice, discipline, and dedication. This might help get you on your way: http://www.coolelf.net/p/how-to-learn.html Good luck!

Comment: 'Welcome, Mike. (Pixar?) Animated films are good for self-study. Keep on learning!

Comment: Mike, I'm afraid I gtg. Catch me again here or at my link

Answer (score 5):

This is used to describe humans - the humans seen are caucasians.

The speaker, being an animal, identified humans as a type of primate, and the adjectives 'freaky' and 'pink' are pretty accurate in this context:

- Freaky meaning different or odd
- Pink meaning, well, pink skinned

Comment: Never actually saw the flick, but this is exactly the dialog my wife and I impugn our cat making every day (with the word "clumsy" thrown in). eg: "Get over here and stractch my neck already, clumsy pink monkey."

Answer (score 1):

I thought of speaker as animal (primate or akin perhaps) at first (too). But a non-pink...whatever...having such vocabulary in regard to kith and kin (why not freaky chimp? Or orange man?) makes it not so certain.

Perhaps they really were pink freaks, as in untanned, hippie-communal-live-for-luv, (Caucasian) returners to their distant cousins' natural abode.